# Group layers and working with them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, group-layer

I've just started with arcgis and I've got a number of different "maps" as individual layers. I've grouped them so it's easier to turn them on and off.
They are choropleth maps, so show counts of things.

Is it possible to assign the same grouping and colour schemes across the layers in one go?

I was thinking : select group layer, apply symbology, categories, join count, and then magic all the layers in the group have the same colour scheme.

Is that possible?

How?

OK Edit:

I've used the information below and learned the model builder and the apply symbology tool will apply any symbology from one layer to a group of layers (which I had to add individually, rather than adding the group layer).This is good. And works quickly!

While it applies the symbology, what I think I want is to set the same grouping across each layer. At the moment I'm counting number of houses per street

0 -   5 Red
6 -  10 Green
11 - 20 Yellow
21 - 30 Orange
31 - 40 Purple
41 - 50 Blue
51+ - Black

How can I apply a standard grouping and colour scheme across the multiple layers?

The maps currently show categories, should it show quantities?
Not every layer will have > 10 houses per street, should I build a template layer that uses all the grouping classes and apply that across the other layers (and ultimately the other map books)?

Comment: What happens when you try what you are thinking about trying?

Comment: It hasn't worked yet. I'm going to try again this evening.

Comment: I don't expect it to work as simply as that but we like askers of questions to always tell us precisely what they have tried and where they got stuck rather than asking for ideas before making that effort.

Comment: You can import an existing symbology with the Import button under Symbology tab. If you want to do it on many layers you can use ArcPy or Modelbuilder, for example with tool Apply Symbology From Layer

Comment: Ok I'll try the model builder. Ive not got an example of what I've done because I've only just got started on the project. My experience with arcgis is minimal and is based on using a map and adding more layers manually. Unfortunately, the project has grown and I'm now trying to build 12 of the same template map books (if that makes sense). I don't really want to just click click click etc and I'd hoped there was a way (non code for right now) to simply select all the layers and then apply all. I'll try the model builder as that looks like it might be a more friendly way to get this done.

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect what I actually want to do and what I've already tried.